# List index out of range,output lines from a text file

Tags: python, loops

I want to pull a certain line from a text file, but it turns out to only take the first one, if I try to call others, this error is displayed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fomen\PycharmProjects\dddf\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    label2 = Label(top, text=list_pip(1), justify=LEFT)
  File "C:\Users\fomen\PycharmProjects\dddf\list_pop.py", line 11, in list_pip
    return list_1[n]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Function:

```
import os

def list_pip(n):
    my_patch = "sort.txt"
    if os.path.getsize(my_patch) > 0:
        list_1 = []
        in_file = open("sort.txt", 'r').readlines()
        for line in in_file:
            line.index(line)
            list_1.append(line)
            return list_1[n]
```

sort.txt:

```
1.1151530742645264
1.448728322982788
1.5068244934082031
3.5338211059570312
```

Comment: Consider what happens after you have appended the first line to `list_1`. What is the value of `n`, and what is the length of `list_1`?

Comment: you have wrong indentation in line with `return` - it exits function after first line. And you try to get `n` when there is only one item - check `len(list_1)` before `return`

Comment: what do you want to get when file has less lines then `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your return statement to `return list_1[n-1]`.

Reason:- Indexing in a list starts from zero. Index 0 of your list gives 1st line, index 1 gives 2nd line, and so on. So, index n-1 gives nth line.

Also, **return statement must be outside for loop**.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indentation in line with `return` - you try to get `[n]` when there is only one line. And you also will return after getting only one line.

There is also other problem - what do you want to get when file is shorter then `n` lines? And what do you want to get when file has size `0`?

```
import os

def list_pip(n):
    my_patch = "sort.txt"

    if os.path.getsize(my_patch) > 0:
        all_lines = []
        in_file = open("sort.txt", 'r')
        for line in in_file:
            line = line.strip() # skip empty lines
            if line:            # skip empty lines
                all_lines.append(line)

        # - after `for`-loop -
        if len(all_lines) > n:
            return all_lines[n]
        else:
            return '???'  # less then `n` lines
     else:
        return '???'  # empty file (getsize() == 0)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You have to also remember that first line has index `0` - so if you want to use `1` to get first line then you have to use `n-1`.

```
    # - after `for`-loop -

    n = n-1

    if len(list_1) > n:
        return list_1[n]
    else:
        return '???'  # less then `n` lines
```

You may also check if `n >= 0` if you don't want to use index `[-1]` which can get last line from list.

```
    # - after `for`-loop -

    n = n-1

    if len(list_1) > n >= 0:
        return list_1[n]
    else:
        return '???'  # less then `n` lines
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with other changes which skips empty lines

```
import os

def list_pip(n, filename='sort.txt'):

    if os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
        all_lines = []
        in_file = open(filename)
        for line in in_file:
            line = line.strip() # skip empty lines
            if line:            # skip empty lines
                all_lines.append(line)

        # - after `for`-loop -
        n -= 1
        if len(all_lines) > n >= 0:
            return all_lines[n]
        else:
            return '???'  # less then `n` lines
    else:
        return '???'  # empty file (getsize() == 0)

for number in range(-1, 7):
    result = list_pip(number)
    print(number, result)
```

And if you want all lines:

```
import os

def list_pip(n, filename='sort.txt'):

    if os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
        all_lines = open(filename).readlines()

        # - after `for`-loop -
        n -= 1
        if len(all_lines) > n >= 0:
            return all_lines[n].rstrip('\n')
        else:
            return '???'  # less then `n` lines
    else:
        return '???'  # empty file (getsize() == 0)

for number in range(-1, 7):
    result = list_pip(number)
    print(number, result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please edit the code as follow:

I hope this becomes a perfect replacement for your code.
An exception was made to account for n greater than number of lines in the file as well as negative values of n

```
       import os

       def list_pip(n):
           my_patch = "sort.txt"
           if os.path.getsize(my_patch) > 0:
               list_1 = []
               in_file = open("sort.txt", 'r').readlines()
               num_lines = len(in_file)
               if n > (num_lines - 1):
                   print("lines in file ended at python index number ", (num_lines - 1)
               elif n < 0:
                   print("lines in file ended at python index number ", (num_lines - 1)
               elif n <= (num_lines - 1):
                    for line in in_file:
                        line.index(line)
                        list_1.append(line)
                    print(list_1[n])
    
      list_pip(3)
      list_pip(4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
        3.5338211059570312
        lines in file ended at python index number 3
```